# screen lock and not displaying lock pattern in android 2.2 (Eclair)

Tags: lock-screens, 2.1-eclair, htc-sense, htc-wildfire

I have HTC Wildfire and one feature I don't like is that it displays the lock composition when I enter incorrect one people knows see the correct one even when displaying password is turned off.

Is it possible to turn it off and/or change to different method of locking screen?

**Edit**: As people didn't notice ***I HAVE "USE VISIBLE PATTERNS" TURNED OFF***. ***It is just when I made mistake it is shown***.

**Edit 2** In Froyo I have option to enter just PIN or even password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, no you can't.

You can install an app that will give you another way to lock phone, like [lockbot](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-jackdoit-lockbot-xjti.aspx).

Of course, rooting will solve the problem...

Comment: At least free version displays with numeric code. But at least I'm on right track.

Comment: plz explain why the down vote?

Comment: Hmm. With custom apps on non-rooted phone HOME button moves to home screen so it is easy to workaround.

Answer (score 4):

Are you entering an actual password, or an unlock-pattern?

Lock-patterns have the option to [display/not-display the path entered](http://www.htc.com/uk/howto.aspx?id=3404&type=1&p_id=316), so it's a lot more difficult to "shoulder-surf"

> **Use visible pattern**   This is selected by default. Clear this if you
>   do not want the screen unlock pattern
>   to display as you enter it.

Comment: As I said I turned it off. However when I enter bad pattern it is still displayed (the wrong I entered).

Answer (score 1):

I think providing feedback as to bad pattern is the fixed behavior and can't be turned off.  I think you are right, it ought not to show you a pattern on error, if you asked to not show a pattern while you were entering it.  Sounds like a good UI change to me, I suggest trying to dig up someplace to post such a criticism.

OTOH, do you really worry about so much shoulder surfing that someone will deduce your pattern from various errors they've seen you make?  Given that it seems unlikely, you might not get much priority on such fix even your request would be consistent behavior.

Comment: "OTOH, do you really worry about so much shoulder surfing that someone will deduce your pattern from various errors they've seen you make?" - given people did do that - yes I do worry (I'm currently studing and some of my colegues have... specific sense  of humor).

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Security, under "Screen unlock pattern" uncheck "Use visible pattern"

Comment: Sorry. But please *READ* questions. I said it was turned off *AND* this answer was already posted.